# I tried to include gpiozero in my custom build with yocto project with raspberry pi 3

Tags: raspberry-pi3, gpiozero, yocto-wic

```
ERROR: core-image-base-1.0-r0 do_rootfs: Could not invoke dnf. Command '/home/jakinboy/projects/build_folder/build_rpi/tmp/work/raspberrypi3_64-poky-linux/core-image-base/1.0-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/bin/dnf -v --rpmverbosity=info -y -c /home/jakinboy/projects/build_folder/build_rpi/tmp/work/raspberrypi3_64-poky-linux/core-image-base/1.0-r0/rootfs/etc/dnf/dnf.conf --setopt=reposdir=/home/jakinboy/projects/build_folder/build_rpi/tmp/work/raspberrypi3_64-poky-linux/core-image-base/1.0-r0/rootfs/etc/yum.repos.d --installroot=/home/jakinboy/projects/build_folder/build_rpi/tmp/work/raspberrypi3_64-poky-linux/core-image-base/1.0-r0/rootfs --setopt=logdir=/home/jakinboy/projects/build_folder/build_rpi/tmp/work/raspberrypi3_64-poky-linux/core-image-base/1.0-r0/temp --repofrompath=oe-repo,/home/jakinboy/projects/build_folder/build_rpi/tmp/work/raspberrypi3_64-poky-linux/core-image-base/1.0-r0/oe-rootfs-repo --nogpgcheck install apt bluez5 bridge-utils dhcp-server hostapd i2c-tools iptables linux-firmware-bcm43430 lshw mywelcome nano packagegroup-base-extended packagegroup-core-boot packagegroup-core-ssh-dropbear psplash-raspberrypi python3 python3-gpiozero run-postinsts sudo wpa-supplicant locale-base-en-us locale-base-en-gb' returned 1:
DNF version: 4.2.2
cachedir: /home/jakinboy/projects/build_folder/build_rpi/tmp/work/raspberrypi3_64-poky-linux/core-image-base/1.0-r0/rootfs/var/cache/dnf
Added oe-repo repo from /home/jakinboy/projects/build_folder/build_rpi/tmp/work/raspberrypi3_64-poky-linux/core-image-base/1.0-r0/oe-rootfs-repo
repo: using cache for: oe-repo
not found other for: 
not found modules for: 
not found deltainfo for: 
not found updateinfo for: 
oe-repo: using metadata from Tue 22 Aug 2023 12:35:22 AM UTC.
Last metadata expiration check: 0:00:01 ago on Tue 22 Aug 2023 12:35:22 AM UTC.
No module defaults found
No match for argument: python3-gpiozero
Error: Unable to find a match


THis is my recipe 
`DESCRIPTION = "Python library for GPIO control"
#HOMEPAGE = "https://gpiozero.readthedocs.io/"
LICENSE = "MIT"
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file://${COMMON_LICENSE_DIR}/MIT;md5=0835ade698e0bcf8506ecda2f7b4f302"

SRC_URI = "file://gpiozero-1.6.2.tar.gz"
SRC_URI[md5sum] = "45dcebab7e92050dcbcf72fb74153468"

#inherit pypi setuptools3

RDEPENDS_${PN} += "python3"

S = "${WORKDIR}"
```

`